# Pentaho Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, cmd, pentaho, job-scheduling

I am trying to schedule a job using a .bat file. When i run it it gets stuck on start of job execution. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue so I can run my jobs?

Does this have anything to do with Java? I do not have the variable PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME. I only have JAVA_HOME. Not sure if it has to do with my kitchen.bat file. I only using Spoon.bat.

I think its a problem with my Kitchen.bat (.kjb) because if i run the batch file with Pan.bat (.ktr) my file runs fine.

```
C:\Users\bxt0\Desktop>c:

C:\Users\bxt\Desktop>cd /d "C:\data-integration"

C:\data-integration>call Kitchen.bat 
  /file:C:\Users\bxt\Desktop\CCMStatsJob.
kjb "-param:TABLE_NAME=region" -logfile=C:\Users\bxt058y\Documents\Pentaho 
  Jobs\
    ccmjob.txt
DEBUG: Using JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_74
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe

C:\data-integration>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe"  "- 
Xms1024m
" "-Xmx2048m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "- 
   Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" "
-Djava.library.path=libswt\win64" "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "- 
  DKET
TLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "- 
DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_L
IMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\pentaho-application-launcher- 
7.1.0.0-
12.jar -lib ..\libswt\win64  -main org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen -initialDir 
 "C
:\data-integration"\ /file:C:\Users\bxt058y\Desktop\CCMStatsJob.kjb "- 
 param:TABL
E_NAME=region" -logfile C:\Users\bxt058y\Documents\Pentaho Jobs\ccmjob.txt
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; 
 sup
port was removed in 8.0
log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender cannot be 
  cast to
   org.apache.log4j.Appender
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.ja
    va:248)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurat
   or.java:176)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfi
  gurator.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOM
   Configurator.java:523)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseCategory(DOMConfigurator.ja
    va:436)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1004)

    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java
    :872)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java
    :755)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:8
   96)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.log4j.Log4jLogging.applyLog4jConfiguratio
  n(Log4jLogging.java:81)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.log4j.Log4jLogging.createLogger(Log4jLogg
    ing.java:89)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.log4j.Log4jLogging.init(Log4jLogging.java
    :68)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleClientEnvironment.initLogginPlugins(KettleC
    lientEnvironment.java:155)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleClientEnvironment.init(KettleClientEnvironm
    ent.java:118)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleClientEnvironment.init(KettleClientEnvironm
     ent.java:79)
    at org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen$1.call(Kitchen.java:91)
    at org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen$1.call(Kitchen.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender cannot be 
   cast to
   org.apache.log4j.Appender
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.ja
    va:248)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurat
    or.java:176)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfi
   gurator.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOM
    Configurator.java:523)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:4
     92)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1006)

    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java
    :872)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java
    :755)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:8
    96)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.log4j.Log4jLogging.applyLog4jConfiguratio
     n(Log4jLogging.java:81)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.log4j.Log4jLogging.createLogger(Log4jLogg
     ing.java:89)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.log4j.Log4jLogging.init(Log4jLogging.java
     :68)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleClientEnvironment.initLogginPlugins(KettleC
     lientEnvironment.java:155)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleClientEnvironment.init(KettleClientEnvironm
    ent.java:118)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleClientEnvironment.init(KettleClientEnvironm
     ent.java:79)
    at org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen$1.call(Kitchen.java:91)
    at org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen$1.call(Kitchen.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    2018/06/28 09:35:32 - Kitchen - Start of run.
    2018/06/28 09:35:34 - CCMStatsJob - Start of job execution
   2018/06/28 09:35:34 - CCMStatsJob - CCMStatsJob
```

Comment: All that work creating that relatively pointless image; please copy and paste the text from the console as formatted code into your question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51083553/edit) instead.

Comment: Alain, If i put that code it just closes and opens without doing anything

Comment: There is no issue with the environment variable. They are setup by the set-pentaho-env.bat, whatever spoon, pan or kitchen. So it of them runs, they all run.

Comment: Your log says the issue is coming from the log4j which cannot open the logfile. As I explain in my answer, Windows thing the logfile is `logfile=C:\Users\bxt058y\Documents\Pentaho` because as it not between quotes it will understand the space as a terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not like white spaces in file names (linux neither). Correct the -logfile.

The parameters must not be between quotes. Remove.

In Window the arguments are introduced by "/" not by "-" (as in linux). Change.

The command `call` executes the process in the background, so you will see nothing, no log not even a signal that the process has stopped. To check it did run correctly you need to type the logfile.

```
kitchen.bat /file:C:\Users\bxt058y\Desktop\CCMStatsJob.kjb /param:TABLE_NAME=region /logfile:"C:\Users\bxt058y\Documents\Pentaho Jobs\ccmjob.txt"
```

Comment: Still open and closes immediately. I posted the log error in my original post (edited)

Comment: Of course the call means to run the command in the background. Please try again it without the first call.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a problem with my Kitchen.bat (.kjb) because if i run the batch file with Pan.bat (.ktr) my file runs fine.

Comment: This is not an answer, please delete it. Also, if you think there's a problem with `Kitchen.bat`, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51083553/edit) to say so, and include the content that batch file.